# Ordering Records in While Loop

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the problem, I'm not sure how to tackle it..let's say I have something like this:

```
SELECT news_key FROM tblNews (WHERE news_key>100);
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rid)) {
  $key=$row['news_key'];

         SELECT articles from tblMain WHERE news_key=$key;
         while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($rid2)) {
         echo ($row['articles']);
         }
  }
```

Now lets say I want to sort the articles by popularity,.so I could change my second query to something like this...

```
         SELECT articles, popularity from tblMain WHERE 
         news_key=$key ORDER BY popularity DESC;
```

But now that isn't going to work..because it's just going to grab records as the first loop finds them.  Also, I've made a really simple illustration here, and I know joining tables on the first query would do this, but the first query in my real life example has a lot of counting and grouping, so I fear that is not an option.  I should also mention I have pagination involved, so the first query gets re-queried each time a page is selected...

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a `JOIN` in this case to join both tables together and order the result. Your query should look something like this:

```
SELECT articles, popularity 
FROM tblNews 
JOIN tblMain 
    ON (tblNews.news_key = tblMain.news_key) 
WHERE news_key > 100 
ORDER BY popularity DESC
```

This way you should be able to get the correct result.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't want to do a join (for whatever reason, if you're worried about locking tables or writing overly complicated SQL), you could load the keys from the first query into an array, order the array, and then iterate through the array to run the second query:

```
// SELECT news_key FROM tblNews (WHERE news_key>100);
// Execute query.
$keysArray = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rid)) {
    $keysArray[] =$row['news_key'];
}
arsort($keysArray);
foreach ($keysArray as $key) {
    // SELECT articles from tblMain WHERE news_key=$key;
    // Execute query.
    while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($rid2)) {
    echo ($row['articles']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions!  I actually have ended up taking your advice and going back and making a join on the first query...it was complicated, but I think I have it.

Many many thanks!